# SUM minutes with condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains duration in minutes.
I would like to add them but when the duration is less than 45 min to return 60 min.

My query returns nothing and is like that:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN duration = 45 THEN duration=60 ELSE 0 END) AS t_dur1 ,
SUM(CASE WHEN duration > 45 THEN duration ELSE 0 END) AS t_dur2
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Apart from the answer below, there might be other reasons that u are not getting the results. Paste your complete query and sample data / expected output for improved answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your logic literally, you only need a single `CASE` statement:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN duration < 45 THEN 60 ELSE duration END) AS t_dur
```

This counts durations which are *less* than 45 minutes as being 60 minutes, otherwise it counts the original value of the duration.

You are probably using this in a `GROUP BY` query looking something like this:

```
SELECT some_col,
       SUM(CASE WHEN duration < 45 THEN 60 ELSE duration END) AS t_dur
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY some_col
```

Comment: I liked the one line solution!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use different comparison operators for your logic:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN duration < 45 THEN 60 ELSE 0 END) AS t_dur1 ,
SUM(CASE WHEN duration >= 45 THEN duration ELSE 0 END) AS t_dur2
```

Your query

```
CASE WHEN duration = 45 THEN duration = 60
```

will always return false, which is actually 0. Note that for example Postgres would raise an error saying something like below:

> CASE types integer and boolean can't be conformed

You may also want to combine both those CASE statements into one:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN duration < 45 THEN 60 ELSE duration END) AS t_dur
```